# Ansible become_user asks for password even though it is configured passwordless

Tags: ansible

I have a strange issue which after many searches, I was not able to find an answer.
It is a very simple case.

Currently there is a linux machine with user x and user y. When I manually login to user x, I can switch user y passwordless using: "sudo su - y".

Now back to ansible.

```
tasks:
- name: test task
  shell: echo "this is a test"
  become: true
  become_user: y
```

This task will connect to the machine using user x. To run the echo it becomes y. For this situation I am getting:
    "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n",

for user y I provided a sudoers file with /bin/sh *, also does not work.
Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For using `sudo su -`, you might have to add the `become_flags` like this:

```
tasks:
- name: test task
  shell: echo "this is a test"
  become: true
  become_method: "sudo"
  become_flags: "su -"
  become_user: y
```

If that does not work, here's something else to try:

```
tasks:
- name: test task
  shell: echo "this is a test"
  become: true
  become_method: "sudo"
  become_flags: "su - -c"
  become_user: y
```

By adding the `-c` flag to `su`, you might be able to work around how Ansible runs the `become` command. In reality, Ansible is not doing two steps (`sudo su - y`, then running the command), but instead running one command in the form of `sudo ... foobarbaz.py`, where the `foobarbaz.py` is script that contains your shell steps (in this case the `echo` command).

To make this work, you have to ensure that your `sudoers` file contains an entry that allows your user to run something like this (if you look at the output of `sudo -l`):

```
su - -c *
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Both suggestions did not work, it gave me this message back.  

Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:
I think the output command was not correct. Why is it so complicated to do something so simple? is there a reason for being so difficult to switch user and execute something?

Comment: Can you post the full output of the command that Ansible is trying to run? It should tell you exactly which command it's trying to run, including the `sudo` part...

Comment: The output of `sudo -l` for user x will be helpful too

Comment: Hi all, I found this on ansible website.

Only one method may be enabled per host
Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user, you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be able to su directly to it (the same for pbrun, pfexec or other supported methods).